# Should I implement both RequestInterface and ServerRequestInterface

Tags: php, request, psr-7, php-fig

I am currently writing an implementation of the [HTTP Message Interface Recommendation (PSR-7)](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/) for my personal PHP framework. I've written classes for each interface in the recommendation. But now I realize that I do not need an abstraction for outbound requests.

At the moment I have:

- `Message` for `MessageInterface`,
- `Request` for `RequestInterface`,
- `Response` for `ResponseInterface`,
- `ServerRequest` for `ServerRequestInterface`,
- `Stream` for `StreamInterface`,
- `UploadedFile` for `UploadedFileInterface`, and,
- `Uri` for `UriInterface`.

I wonder if I must implement every interface of the recommendation to claim my framework uses it? Or may I only implement the parts of I need?

Comment: You don't need to implement a class for each interface. It depends on your needs.

Comment: Thank you. Upon further research, I learned that some server focused libraries, like the Slim framework, did not implement RequestInterface directly. I decided to do the same.

https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/Http/Request.php